# I am getting error when running this loop

Tags: python, list, sorting

You are given an array of integers `a`. A new array `b` is generated by rearranging the elements of `a` in the following way:

`b = [a[0], a[len(a)-1], a[1], a[len(a)-2, ...]`

my code only loops for one time, and I am just stuck from here. What I have tried is below

```
def alternatingSort(a):
    length = len(a)
    b = []
    for i in range(length):
        if i % 2:
            b.append(a[length-i])
        else:
            b.append(a[i])
    return b
```

if my input is `[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2]`, my output should be `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
But i get `[1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3]`.

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve], your question is off-topic without it. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask], they explain a few more beginners' mistakes.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt He did provide a reproducible example.

Comment: No, @ba_ul: I just gave above code to a Python interpreter and it didn't do anything (except that it defines a function). The point of that [mcve] is to remove any bit of guessing involved in answering the question.

Comment: OK @UlrichEckhardt, I see what you mean. But it was close enough and much better than most questions on SO. Just add `input = [1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2]` and then run `alternatingSort(input)`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt will do that for next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is not correct. Here, is the working solution with minimum changes:

```
def alternatingSort(a):
    length = len(a)
    b = []
    for i in range(length):
        if i % 2:
            b.append(a[length - (i // 2) - 1])    # Updated.
        else:
            b.append(a[i // 2])                   # Updated.

    return b

a = [1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2]
print(alternatingSort(a))

a = [1, 3 ,2]
print(alternatingSort(a))
```